# How to compute metrics on cpu when training on multi gpus by pytorch lightning?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, multi-gpu

When training on multi gpus by pytorch lightning, I can't compute metrics on cpu on validation step.
The code following only operates validation on one of gpus.
I guess it is beacuse of the function cpu().

```
    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # batch size = 1
        assert batch["image"].shape[0] == 1

        labels, trimaps, dataset_name, image_name = batch["alpha"], batch["trimap"], batch["dataset_name"], batch["image_name"]

        output, guidance_map = self.shared_step(batch, batch_idx)
        
        label = labels.squeeze().cpu().numpy()*255.0
        trimap = trimaps.squeeze().cpu().numpy()*128
        pred = output.squeeze().cpu().numpy()*255.0
        
        metrics_unknown, metrics_all = self.compute_four_metrics(
            pred, label, trimap)
```

How can I move the tensors to cpu correctly when using multi gpu training in pytorch lightning?